# Start Broadcast Unity Network Discovery

Tags: unity, c#, networking, unity-networking

I am using the unity `NetworkDiscovery` component, and I am wondering how I can auto-start broadcasting when the server starts, instead of the client having to click on the gui: `Initialize Broadcast` => `Start Broadcasting`. I would like to be able to put some `C#` in my start host function so that the user does not have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas, if possible subscribe to a "Start server event", if thats not available, you could try a Timer , onElapsedTime event and try connectiong every few seconds, until it works, and when it does turn the timer off.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I am a bit new to unity and I am wondering how exactly I would go about doing this? Could you give me some example code? Thank you!

Comment: @pudility do you have any code efforts that you can share?